# doOnUnsubscribe called not on Observable thread

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

For now `doOnTerminate(...)` always called on `IO Scheduler` thread and `doOnUnsubscribe(...)` on `UI thread Scheduler` (main in Android)

```
fun <T> withTransaction(sourceObservable: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    ...
    return Observable.empty<T>()
            .doOnCompleted { startTransaction() }
            .mergeWith(sourceObservable)
            .doOnNext { setTransactionSuccessful() }
            .doOnTerminate(...) // called on RxIoScheduler-2 thread
            .doOnUnsubscribe(...) // called on main thread
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) // didn't help
}
```

How can I force doOnUnsubscribe to be executed on IO thread?

Comment: What you ask for is what is happening now? Do you mean to ask how to get unsubscribe on io thread?

Comment: @DaveMoten yes. There was a mistake in my question. Fixed: _How can I force doOnUnsubscribe to be executed on IO thread?_

Comment: Can you provide some runnable code pls. I've tried using `empty.doOnUnsubscribe.subscribeOn.toBlocking.subscribe` and no problem.

Comment: Try with `unsubscribeOn(io())`.

Comment: @DaveMoten Blocking observable called on current thread. I want it to run async on io.

Comment: @akarnokd thank! It works.